# How do I shift/remap one range of colors to another in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

I have attached an image to hopefully explain better, but if say I have an image that ranges from color 'A' to 'C', and I want it to range from 'B' to 'D' instead - what is the best method?

I'm sure it has something to do with color range or similar. I'm aware of the Hue + Colorise method, but it doesn't allow me to pick the end point colors (B and D).

(Also ignore the shadow in the image.)

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try these

1 -  go to layers> new adjustment   layer>gradient map and apply yourcolors.

[image: Gradient map] 
i tried a lil to show you the thing,adjust your color scheme accordingly :)

2 - image>adjustment>replace color

Comment: Seriously fantastic - I have been trying to figure that out for ages! (btw. Number 1 worked for my situation)

Comment: That's a good way to do it, but be sure to mask off your Earth (and it's reflection) so that the shadow doesn't get remapped (and stays gray)... if you want it to stay gray.  (^_^)

Answer (score 0):

easier way is to edit its hue. go to edit > adjustments > hue & saturation (in short: ctrl + U). Play around with the hue till you find your color and you are done.